# Call for All Posts for an Organization Only Returns Posts in Past Year

Tags: python-requests, linkedin-api

In attempting to fetch [All posts for my LinkedIn organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2022-11&tabs=http#batch-get-posts), not all posts are returned in the paginated GET call:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/posts?author={org_urn_encoded}&isDsc=false&q=author&count={paginate_count}&start={current}
```

Paginating in groups of 100 (maximum allowed per call), my API calls return a set of less than half of the total posts my organization has made (ex. 194/805+). The posts line up almost perfectly to the past year.

There is no documentation noting timeframes or retrieving in a timeframe for the Posts API.

Any idea in how to get more than just the past year for an organization's posts?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

same happening to me since a few days. seems to be a LinkedIn bug, i've created a support ticket, please do the same on https://linkedin.zendesk.com/ expecting a solution from LinkedIn developer support.

NOTE: I've also tried using versioned endpoint https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?....

This is not happening using legacy 'ugcPosts' and shares 'endpoints'.

Hope this info could help you!